# Print my recursive factorial result

Tags: java, methods, factorial, println

I need to print my final answer for my method. However, it shows the whole calculation to the end! How can I eliminate the process to get only the result?

Comment: Call ths from another method and print the result.

Comment: @r0ast3d is this the only way?

Comment: yep @Niloo posted an answer with pseudo

Comment: What's the variable `b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recursive function call, which is executed in all the cases without special condition checks.
printing from another method is a good option.

```
private static int getFactorial(int userInput){
    int ans = userInput;
    if(userInput >1 ){

    ans*= (getFactorial(userInput-1));
    }
    return ans;

}
// New method;
private static void printFactorial(int userInput){
    System.out.println("The value of " + userInput + "! is " + getFactorial(userInput));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, call your method from another one and only print the final value:

```
System.out.println(getFactorial(5));
```

If you really need to do it from inside the method you can create a sort of "trampoline" method, like so:

```
private static int getFactorial(int userInput) {
    int fact = _getFactorial(userInput);
    System.out.println(fact);
    return fact;
}

private static int _getFactorial(int userInput) {
    // real implementation
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but is this the only way?

Comment: @Niloo I added a possible alternative, but I wouldn't recommend it if you don't absolutely need it.

Comment: you can use static variables, and 
use if(userInput = actualInputInstaticVariable){ // print. }
This means that there are ways.. but not the ones that someone will need

Answer (score 0):

```
// Calculate the factorial value
private static int getFactorial(int userInput){
    int ans = userInput;
    if(userInput >1 ){

    ans*= (getFactorial(userInput-1));

    }

     return ans;
}
```

and print outside the function

```
System.out.println("The value of "+ b +"! is "+ getFactorial(b));
```

Print only once, when you got the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't like the idea of just returning a value and printing from the caller code, you can add a "print the answer" flag as an argument:

```
// Calculate the factorial value
private static int getFactorial(int value, boolean print){
    if (value > 1) {

        value *= getFactorial(value-1, false);

        if (print) {
            System.out.println("The value of "+ b +"! is "+ value);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Personally, though, I'd prefer the "trampoline method" of [Jake King's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946989/535871).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Calculate the factorial value
private static int getFactorial(int userInput){
    int ans = userInput;
    if(userInput >1 ){

    ans*= (getFactorial(userInput-1));

    //System.out.println("The value of "+ b +"! is "+ ans);
    }
    return ans;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int ans;
    //get input
    ans = getFactorial(input);
    System.out.println("The value of "+ b +"! is "+ ans);
}
```